# CSS: Opacity Issue

Tags: css

Ok, so in my page I am showing a background image with this css:

```
.heroarea {
    background:url(/static/images/mrd_hero_01.jpg) no-repeat;
    height:450px;
}
```

and the copy placed over it and the container the copy is in have these styles:

```
.main-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 380px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 560px;
    height: 340px;
    padding: 30px 30px 20px 30px;
    /* CSS3 standard */
    opacity:0.5;
    /* for IE */
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}
.main-panel h1 {
    background: transparent;
    color:#39372f;
    text-align: center;
    /* CSS3 standard */
    opacity:1;
    /* for IE */
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Generally, everything is as expected. That is, the image shows where I expect it to show. main-panel shows a white back ground with a transparent background. However, the text in the h1 tag is also transparent. I can see the image from underneath showing through. How can I make this so that the h1 tag content is not opaque?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opacity applies to the element, not it's background.

You either need to use a translucent image, or an rgba background colour.

There is an [explanation about how to do this in a backwards compatible way](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/). (Disclosure: My site)

Comment: This is a nice and clean way to do it! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

You have to move it outside of its `.main-panel` parent.  There's no way to override the 50% opacity that's being applied there.

Alternatively, if you're only using 50% opacity to make the `mrd_hero_01.jpg` background image transparent, you could convert it to a .png with 50% opacity and then you wouldn't need to set the opacity on `.main-panel`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [rgba](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) and/or transparent png. Alternatively, move the content to a separate sibling div as the background:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="opacity"></div>
   <div id="child">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use transparency on a block element it makes the child element inside transparent as well.This is how css works !  I do not think there is any way to hack out of it. What you can do it to absolutely position h1 without making it a child or use a translucent image

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your text is a child of .main-panel. It will take on 50% opacity. Even though you state the text is opacity 100% will only make it 100% of 50%. You will need to layer it outside of .main-panel and place it on top.